# Trace of $x(x^\top x)^{-1}x^\top$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Let $x_i^\top=(1,x_{1,i}\ldots,x_{d,i})\in\mathbb{R}^{1\times d+1}$ for $i\in\{1,\ldots, n\}$ linearly independent and $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times d+1}$, where the $i$-th row of $x$ equals $x_i^\top$. I want to find the trace of the matrix this matrix, i.e. $$\operatorname{tr}( x(x^\top x)^{-1} x^\top)$$ It is easy to show, that $$(x(x^\top x)^{-1} x^\top)^2=x(x^\top x)^{-1} x^\top$$
and
$$(x(x^\top x)^{-1} x^\top)^\top=x(x^\top x)^{-1} x^\top$$
such that trace and rank are the same:
$$\operatorname{tr}( x(x^\top x)^{-1} x^\top)=\operatorname{rk}( x(x^\top x)^{-1} x^\top)$$

However, I still struggle to find $\operatorname{rk}( x(x^\top x)^{-1} x^\top)$. My guess is that it is $d$ oder $d+1$, but I am not able to show this.

Any hint or help is appriciated!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that whenever the product $AB$ is defined, we have $\operatorname{tr}(AB) = \operatorname{tr}(BA)$. It follows that
$$
\operatorname{tr}(x[(x^\top x)^{-1}x^\top]) = \operatorname{tr}([(x^\top x)^{-1}x^\top]x) = \operatorname{tr}((x^\top x)^{-1}(x^\top x)) = \operatorname{tr}(I) = d+1.
$$

Comment: Oh, I see, but I think it must be $d+1$ then, because $x$ is a $\mathbb{R}^{n\times (d+1)}$ matrix, right?

Comment: @user408858 Yes, the answer should be $d+1$, see my edit. I misunderstood your question initially; I thought that $x$ is a column-vector.

Comment: @user408858 As an alternative approach, you could note that $x^\top x$ is invertible, which means that $x^\top x$ has rank $d+1$, which must mean that $x$ has rank at least $d+1$ (since $\operatorname{rank}(AB) \leq \operatorname{rank}(B)$. But the maximal possible rank of $x$ is $\min\{d+1,n\} = d+1$.